# How to get the values checked if they match

Tags: laravel

I have eager-loaded all the grades with subjects in the database, I want all the grades and subjects associated with the user to be checked when I edit the user, but its not checked... what am I doing wrong?

```
public function edit($id)
    {
       
        $classes = Grade::with('subjects')->get();
       
        return view('profiles.edit', compact( 'classes'));  
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($classes as $class)
    <div class="card shadow mx-2 my-4">
        <div class="card-header bg-light py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="{{$class->id}}" name="class[]"
                        value="{{ $class->name }}"
                        {{ (is_array(old('class')) && in_array( $class->name, old('class', $user->class))) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                    <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</label>
                </div>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach($class->subjects as $subject)
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror"
                    id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" name="subjects[]" value="{{ $subject->name }}"
                    {{ (is_array(old('subjects')) && in_array( $subject->name, old('subjects', $user->subjects))) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

dd($classes->toArray());
[image]

Comment: what is `$user->subjects` inside ? only name array or id name etc..?

Comment: inside $user->subjects there is an array

Comment: whats the relationship between class and user ?? is it many to many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have you use `$user->subjects()->pluck('name')->toArray()`

```php
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror"
id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" name="subjects[]" value="{{ $subject->name }}"
{{ (is_array(old('subjects')) && in_array( $subject->name, old('subjects', $user->subjects()->pluck('name')->toArray()))) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check those if statements in controller and if it is true set some index in your array and in blade check that index.
this way you are doing is confusing. but at least you can do something like this:

```
@if(....)
 <input ... checked />
@else
<input ... />
@endif
```

look at this sample code for short if statement in input. im sure it will help you

```
<input type="checkbox" id="total_distance" {{$value1 == $value2 ? 'checked' : ''}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always checking if old inputs are arrays in your conditionals (If there was no old inputs they couldn't be arrays). If there is an "old" input named `subjects` that is an array you would not get the chance to compare the User's subjects; because `old('subjects', ...)` would return that array always and not fallback to the default argument.

If `$user->subjects` is a Collection of Models you can see if that Collection "contains" the `$subject`:

```
in_array($subject->name, (array) old('subjects'))
    || $user->subjects->contains($subject)
```

If `$user->subjects` is an array of subject names:

```
|| in_array($subject->name, $user->subjects)
```

You also could merge the two arrays together:

```
$list = array_merge((array) old('subjects'), $user->subjects);

in_array($subject->name, $list) ? 'checked' : ''
```

I am assuming this is the functionality you are trying to achieve but not sure. This basically would make sure the checkbox is checked if the old input array contains the subject or the user has the subject.

Answer (score 0):

heres a solution for you to try assuming relationship between user and class is many to many, and same thing for user and subjects :

**In your controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
       
        $classes = Grade::with('subjects')->get();
        return view('profiles.edit', compact( 'classes'));  
    }
```

**In your view**

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($classes as $class)
    <div class="card shadow mx-2 my-4">
        <div class="card-header bg-light py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="{{$class->id}}" name="class[]"
                        value="{{ $class->name }}"
                        {{ (is_array($class->id, old('class', [])) || $user->class->contains($class->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                    <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</label>
                </div>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach($class->subjects as $subject)
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror"
                    id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" name="subjects[]" value="{{ $subject->name }}"
                    {{ (is_array($subject->id, old('subjects', [])) || $user->subjects->contains($subject->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```